# Vanishing of Ext group and Krull dimension

Tags: commutative-algebra

Suppose $A=k[x_1,..,x_n]_{(x_1,..,x_n)}$, it is a regular local ring of dimension $n$. Let $B=A/I$ be a quotient ring of Krull dimension $r$. How to show $\operatorname{Ext}_A^i(B,A)=0$ for $i<n-r$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have $\dim A=\dim A/I+\operatorname{ht}I$, so $\operatorname{ht}I=n-r$. Then $\operatorname{grade}I=n-r$ and now use the Rees theorem (see Bruns and Herzog, Theorem 1.2.5).

Comment: It's enough to assume that $A$ is local and Cohen-Macaulay.